# When do you need to use JSON Web Token authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, jwt

I have a Rails app using Vue.js for some front-end components. I use Devise for authentication, but since some of my Vue components make JSON requests to my backend, should I be using something like JWT authentication? I'm confused about when Devise is enough and when some type of JSON web token authentication becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a Single Page Application, maybe you need a JWT.  The user must login once at the beginning, after login you will have a Json Web Token, and the next requests need to use the token in order to authenticate.

You can take a look a devise-jwt gem, to implement these feature.

https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt